# Create two views this the same url and different permissions

Tags: 7, views, users

I would like to build a set of views, all of which use the same url.  I also want to set up role based permissions for each one so each users get routed to a different view when they visit the url (the url which all the views share.)  Is it possible to build this view system?

My final goal is to have a single navbar link which sends normal users to a view that filters content based on the users NID.  Admin users will be sent sent to a view that shows everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the views as blocks and configure each one to display according to the permissions you're interested in, then place all blocks on a single page and link to it. The system will try to load all blocks, but will not show the ones the user doesn't have access to.

One caveat is a privileged user (such as admin) seeing their AND "lower permission" views, but that can be worked around, too.